# Received an ARC Semantic Issue how to fix?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I am currently starting to use cocos2d 3.0 on Xcode. When I started to run it, I received an error on the 7th line. `[child wasRunning:wasRunning]`; 
I don't know how to fix this, could anyone help me? The error was 
No visible @interface for 'CCNode' declares the selector 'wasRunning'

```
static void
RecursivelyIncrementPausedAncestors(CCNode *node, int increment) {
    for(CCNode *child in node->_children){
        BOOL wasRunning = child.runningInActiveScene;
        child->_pausedAncestors += increment;
        [child wasRunning:wasRunning];

        RecursivelyIncrementPausedAncestors(child, increment);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

because there is no such method as `wasRunning` in the CCNode class. May be you subclassed CCNode to some XYZ class. If so, then type cast `child` to that class and then call the method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding

```
-(void)wasRunning:(BOOL)wasRunning;
```

in CCNode.h, but then I had another similar problem in CCScheduler.m file, line 89 : CCScheduledTarget does not have a member named _paused.

I just created a new cocos2D project, didn't change anything and I have those problems.
So I think that adding -(void)wasRunning:(BOOL)wasRunning; is not the good solution if I have other similar problems.
I have Xcode 4.5.2 and Cocos2D 3.1.0.